# why can't Jenkins see some System32 files?

Tags: command-line, jenkins

**Situation :**

The slave in question is a real Windows (not VM)

**Problem :**

I run the following windows line command on my system

```
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

When I try to run it through Jenkins, I got this message :
'Bcdedit.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why? Throught Jenkins I cannot see this file with `dir` in System32 either

Comment: The path to Bcdedit.exe is declared in the PATH variable?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question but I've worked around it by copying executables from C:\Windows\System32 to another path (such as C:\bin) and adding it to the Path environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that when I run `bcdedit.exe`, it goes to `System32`, and because the Jenkins application we have is 32 bits, Windows 7 redirect acces to `System32` to `SysWOW64` which doesn't have the `bcdedit.exe`.

To know more about this redirection, see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

To solve it, I executed the file with the whole path, and instead of System32, I use the word sysnative (explanation here for sysnative) : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/28974b59-1b79-44fd-8bb2-a0a412e18862/script-to-disable-64bit-file-system-redirection

Comment: Thank you for this answer! In my case I also suspected smth similar to happen and it was. My Jenkins showed it takes java.exe from System32 ("where java.exe"), but the file was not there, instead I found it in SysWOW64. This effect is not visible in a batch console, because it is 64-bit. Very annoying MS feature. I am curious, how and whether it is possible to force "dir C:\Windows\System32" which is run from a 32-bit App not showing content of  C:\Windows\SysWOW64 instead.